# appbar/toolbar overlapping view in constraint layout

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-constraintlayout

I've six buttons in a vertical chain using a constraint layout.  In my emulator it looks fine.  You can ignore the two buttons on either side.   I added them for perspective.
 [image]

when I put the app on the the actual corresponding device I get a very different view.  The toolbar overlaps my top button and the nav bar overlaps my bottom button.

[image]

I've read were the emulator isn't always correct.  Given that, how can I account for the height of the toolbar and navigation bar in my constraint layout.  Below is my xml. The six buttons are named x21 to x26 in my xml below.  I apologize for the length of it.  Is there a way to fix this in my xml or do I need to calculate the toolbar and nav bar height in my code and update the margin of the top and bottom button.  If I need to do this in my code how would I do this. Or might there be another approach  I'm grateful for any advice. 
Thanks

```
<com.example.android.cop1803.LayoutCustom xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mylayoutcustom"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clipToPadding="false"
tools:context="com.example.android.cop1803.MainActivity"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="73dp">


<com.example.android.cop1803.MyViewbutton
    android:id="@+id/MainCOPbtn"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/layoutwidthMaincopbutton"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/layoutheightMaincopbutton"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/copbuttonmaineffect"
    android:text="@string/x11MainCOPtext"
    android:textAppearance="@style/MainButtonFontStyle"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.14"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

    />
 <com.example.android.cop1803.MyViewbutton
    android:id="@+id/x21"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/layoutwidthcopbutton"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/layoutheightcopbutton"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/copbutton"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:text="@string/x21BreadingCrustCoatingsWraps"
    android:textAppearance="@style/ButtonFontStyle"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/x22"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread" />


<com.example.android.cop1803.MyViewbutton
    android:id="@+id/x22"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/layoutwidthcopbutton"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/layoutheightcopbutton"
    android:background="@drawable/copbutton"
    android:paddingLeft="1dp"
    android:paddingRight="1dp"
    android:text="@string/x22CuttingandManipulation"
    android:textAppearance="@style/ButtonFontStyle"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/x23"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/x21" />

<com.example.android.cop1803.MyViewbutton
    android:id="@+id/x23"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/layoutwidthcopbutton"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/layoutheightcopbutton"
    android:background="@drawable/copbutton"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:text="@string/x23DryRubsandStuffings"
    android:textAppearance="@style/ButtonFontStyle"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/x24"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/x22" />

<com.example.android.cop1803.MyViewbutton
    android:id="@+id/x24"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/layoutwidthcopbutton"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/layoutheightcopbutton"
    android:background="@drawable/copbutton"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:text="@string/x24HerbandSpicePastes"
    android:textAppearance="@style/ButtonFontStyle"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/x25"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/x23" />

<com.example.android.cop1803.MyViewbutton
    android:id="@+id/x25"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/layoutwidthcopbutton"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/layoutheightcopbutton"
    android:background="@drawable/copbutton"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:text="@string/x25MarinadesandBrines"
    android:textAppearance="@style/ButtonFontStyle"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/x26"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/x24" />

<com.example.android.cop1803.MyViewbutton
    android:id="@+id/x26"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/layoutwidthcopbutton"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/layoutheightcopbutton"
    android:background="@drawable/copbutton"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:text="@string/x26SpicesandSpiceCrusts"
    android:textAppearance="@style/ButtonFontStyle"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/x27"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/x25" />

<com.example.android.cop1803.MyViewbutton
    android:id="@+id/x27"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/layoutwidthcopbutton"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/layoutheightcopbutton"
    android:background="@drawable/copbutton"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:text="@string/x27Balance"
    android:textAppearance="@style/ButtonFontStyle"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/x26" />

<com.example.android.cop1803.MyViewbutton
    android:id="@+id/x31"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/layoutwidthMedcopbutton"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/layoutheightMedcopbutton"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/copbuttonsecond"
    android:paddingLeft="1dp"
    android:paddingRight="1dp"
    android:text="@string/x31CookingTechniques"
    android:textAppearance="@style/ButtonFontStyle"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.64"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />



<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.android.cop1803.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >
        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_main"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <include
        android:id="@+id/cartlist"
        layout="@layout/content_main" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think u mean action bar. Try to add action bar margin to the root element of your XML.

```
 android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
```

Comment: This worked for my action bar, i just added a horizontal guideline and set the begin to this attribute.  I then constrained my top button to the guideline.  How would I handle the nav bar on the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"` to

`app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/coordinator_layout"`.

When you provide constraint as parent, it takes your parent layout container, which includes the toolbar as well. Instead you want to constraint it below the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

At the top where the `ConstraintLayout` is first set up add the last line from below T:

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"    
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```